# Nativescript – center horizontal text inside textView, dynamic text and multiline

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I've got a nativescript app. I have a situation were I need to display text dynamically, so I don't know how much text and how much lines it will be.

The text need to wrap over multi lines and has to be **aligned in center** horizontally (not vertically, simply same distance to left and right) always.

Therefore I guess `<Label>` isn't the right element, because it is not for multiline (if I got this right?!).

So I choose `<TextView>`, but here the styles `text-align: center` got ignored.

So in documentation I found constructor **textAlignment** https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/modules/_ui_text_base_#textalignment, but I don't get it to work.

Doesn't work:

```
<TextView  text="{{ taskString }}"
    horizontalAlignment="center"
    editable="false"
 ></TextView>
```

Doesn't work:

```
<TextView  text="{{ taskString }}"
    textAlignment="center"
    editable="false"
 ></TextView>
```

Please let me know, what obvious I didn't get here. Thx.

**Upate:**
Label with `textWrap="true"` normally works just fine. But I have a "complex" `<ContentView> <FlexboxLayout>` combination, that seems to cause the problem with the height of Label that doesn't get updated.

**Solution in my case:**
Just don't use a `<FlexboxLayout> <FlexboxLayout> ... </FlexboxLayout> </FlexboxLayout>`solution. That won't calculate the height of Label dynamically.

**Nativescript Playground:**
https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=SnNmkQ

Comment: The CSS `text-align` is doing the same as the inline `textAlignment` and should work as expected- here is a Playground demo - notice that to align a samller view inside its parent you will need horizontalAlignment as well.

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=5ynYmi&v=4

Comment: This seems to work only, if the with of textView isn't 100% of it's parent. An simple text-align: center doesn't work here for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label can be multiline if you enable `textWrap`

**XML**

```
<Label text="{{ taskString }}" textWrap="true" ...
```

Or

**CSS**

```
Label {
   white-space: normal;
}
```

Comment: Oh no, it doesn't work as expected. If I change the text dynamically, text get over two lines, only on first time. Is text is short at the beginning, and gets manipulated to long, there is only one line, because Label is not high enough.

Comment: Please share a Playground example where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: great idea. Sorry for inconvenience.

The problem comes from my Layout solution, not from the <Label texWrap=true> itself.

So I have to find a solid solution for the layout. Updated post with playground url.

Thank you very much.